# How to know number of items returned by query in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this query in my Firebase

```
 mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("animals);
      query = mDataBase.orderByChild("height").limitToLast(20);
     query.addChildEventListener(new AnimalsEventListener());
```

My listener

```
private class AnimalsEventListener implements ChildEventListener{

private AnimalsEventListener(){
}

@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
  Animals details = dataSnapshot.getValue(Animals.class);
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
}
```

How can I get the size of all animals that matched the query before working on dataSnapShot? sometimes they can be less than 20;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to know children count using `ChildEventListener`, use `ValueEventListener` instead.

```
public class AnimalsEventListener implements ValueEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 20) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshotEntry : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Animals details = dataSnapshotEntry.getValue(Animals.class);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
}
```

To attach this listener, use `addValueEventListener()` method

```
query.addValueEventListener(new AnimalsEventListener());
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. i think i had misunderstood `ValueEventListener` `onDataChange()`. kudos for reminding me

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use childEventListener i recommend u to use official [FirebaseArray class](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java).

To get the item count:

```
FirebaseArray mFirebaseArray = FirebaseArray(Query ref);
mFirebaseArray.getCount();
```

Comment: Wow, looks great. Can you give an example on how to use this class including how to attach the listener? I can't find any example on the internet for android.

Comment: Via the same link u can find firebaes ui related classes. Or u can use directly firebas ui library. Here is the recycleradapter where firebase array is implemented with listeners. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java

Comment: @uguboz how sure can one be that when you call `mFirebaseArray.getCount()` all items will have been added to the arraylist?

Comment: when u create an instance of FirebaseArray it will start fetching items immediately. if you implement listeners you dont need to know if all the items added or still adding as it may change with childevents. u should do ur work when it matches ur criteria.